# Hover over images to reveal text (centered vertically)

Tags: jquery, css

This may seem like a standard question, but I'm after some 'best practice' here. Around the web (a good example is designspiration.net) you have sites that have images, that when hovered, reveal a block/alpha colour with text (usually a title, caption or number) positioned in the centre both horizontally and vertically.

In the past I've usually hacked my way through to achieve this effect, but it would be great to know the best and most effective/semantic way to do this (CSS? jQuery? Both?)

If you look at the designspiration landing page and hover over the images, you'll get the idea. Note these images don't have a fixed height.

Any implementation would be really appreciated (jsFiddle etc) and hopefully this'll help others.

Many thanks
Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vertical-allign: middle;`!
http://jsfiddle.net/zR4kk/

You just have to make your container `display:table`
And your content `display: table-cell`

HTML

```
<div class="area">
     <p>To look best, text should really be centered inside this div both vertically and horizontally.</p>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.area { 
  width: 300px; 
  height: 300px; 
  background: green; 
  display:table;
    padding:5px;
}

.area p {
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  text-align: center; 
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

For this particular case, the solution that designspiration uses is method 4 from this blog post: [Vertical Centering with CSS](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/).

```
<style>
    .container {
        position: relative; /* or absolute, if needed */
    }

    .covering {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; left: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
    .container:hover .covering {
        opacity: 0.9;
    }

    .background {
        width: 100%; height: 100%;
        background: white;
    }
    .foreground {
        height: 30px;
        bottom: 0; right: 0;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<!-- floated so that it fits the image; position: absolute would also work -->
<div class="container" style="float: left">
    <img src="(source image)" />
    <div class="covering background"></div>
    <div class="covering foreground">
        This will be centered
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually have a problem with the text is multi-lined. I have given access to the page so hopefully you can help. Hover over the images and all you'll see what I mean (bottom left is multi-lined text). Any help or ideas would be great. http://goo.gl/NrTqX